# Как подменить свой контент который выводя через iframe на чужих сайтах?

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

Мой контент выводят конкуренты на своих сайтах через iframe таким кодом:

```
<iframe src="//video.site.ru/xxx?kp_id=123" width="560" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Я точно помню что можно как-то с помощью **.htaccess** сделать чтобы на вывод получалось другое содержимое(например картинка) или другой видео-ролик. Но не помню как это делается.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать заголовок **Referer**, его можно настроить через .htaccess. Проблема в том, что это не всегда может  сработать, в случае если браузер скрывает некоторые хедеры. Я рекоменду вам на ваших страницах реализовать что то вроде

```
<script>
    if(window.parent !== window) {
        location.href = 'path/to/redirect';
    }
</script>
```

Хотя лучше использовать эти методы одновременно.

Comment: одновременно -- самое оно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Так автру же нужна была переадресация, а не полный запрет. Как я уже говорил некоторые браузеры могут игнорировать этот хедер.